Particle system not working in workbench render
Just like the title, the particle system works fine in eevee (I didn't render as animation), but when I try to render in workbench only the emitter shows up. I need to render fast for a preview so i used workbench. Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gKpkr3Xi1z1Ibq5Gr2FlEwU4Oye9yfet/view?usp=sharing

Use View > Viewport Render Animation from the 3D Viewport menu. But be aware (I don't know anything of your particle setup) that if the particle simulation is not baked, it might also be that it is not recalculated for rendering.
